# how to convert sharedpreferences data to hashmap in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-tablelayout

I have created shared preferences as below:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
    getSharedPreferences("PREF_FILE_NAME",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

and put the value as shown below:

```
editor.putLong(parser.nextText().toString(), i);
```

where I increase the value.

It is stored fine.

Now I want to retrieve that value because I want to show it in table layout, but I don't know how.

So what is easiest way to do this? Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Iterating `Preferences` using `Map`.

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();
```

Then you can easily iterate using Entry,

```
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
   Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + 
                                   entry.getValue().toString());            
 }
```

Comment: But i want directly value of i i.e. i have used
 keys.get(k).toString()
but it shows forcefully closed

Comment: i want to show this values in textviews that are dynamically created..
so what i m write in textview.settext()

Comment: keys are stored in map also...with value

Comment: i have done.. i got 15%=34 i.e. at i=34 value is 15% now i want k at 34th place of textview i want to print 15%.. how it is possible??
plz help me as i m beginner in android

Comment: But putString or putlong doesnt allow me to store integer value in it. it shows that swap values ..